# reveal.js fullscreen programmatically

Tags: configuration, initialization, fullscreen, reveal.js

Is there a programmatical way to set a revealjs 4 presentation to fullscreen, similar to the "f" key functionality? The intention is to have the presentation run permanently in fullscreen on a *Windows 10 Home* tablet with as little unintended user interaction and OS-related layout as possible. (Since this is a low-budget project kiosk mode is not an option, since this is only available in *Windows Pro* and *Enterprise* versions.) I've tried plugins, but all of them are made to respond to some input, such as a button click, key stroke or gesture. However the solution that I need is to have the whole presentation run in fullscreen without any input needed to trigger that.